# Get scrapy spider to crawl entire site

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl old sites that I own, I am using the code below as my spider. I don't mind having files outputted for each webpage, or a database with all the content within that. But I do need to be able to have the spider crawl the whole thing with out me having to put in every single url that I am currently having to do

```
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com/contactus"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To crawl whole site you should use the [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) instead of the `scrapy.Spider`

[Here's an example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example)

For your purposes try using something like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Also, take a look at this [article](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html)

Comment: You probably want to add `follow=True` to that rule, to continue crawling links.

Comment: @Daniil Mashkin, your solution also helped me, thanks for that, but now i wonder what does the [-2] is for? thanks in advance. How can i save all my scraped links into a .csv file? if i run"scrapy crawl spider -o .example.csv" i get an empty .csv file :/

Comment: @y.y you should have your own [Item class](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#item-objects) with `url` field and just return it in the `parse_item` method. Then your `scrapy crawl spider -o .example.csv` will work fine

Comment: or try 
`return {'url': response.url}`

Comment: @Daniil Mashkin i can confirm that, thanks. do you know how i can check all my scraped links, which are stored in a csv file, for productlinks and maybe some categorylinks? that i got in the end one csv with productfiles and one with categorylinks

Comment: @y.y with using ` -o ` argument you will always get one file. You can add `type` to your Item class or `type` field to the returned dict.

Comment: @Daniil Mashkin can you please have a look at: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63244941/scrapy-spider-crawl-infinite>