# Scrapy spider crawl infinite

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

**Task**
My spider should be able to crawl every link of the whole domain and should recognize, if its a productlink or for example a categorylink, but only writes productlinks to items.

I set a rule which allows URLs containing "a-" because its contained in every productlink.

my if-condition should simply check, if there is productean listed, if yes, then its double checked and should be definitely a productlink

After that process it should save link in my list

**Problem**
Spider collect all links instead of parsing links if "-a" is contained

**Edited: Code is used**

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from ..items import LinkextractorItem

class TopArtSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "topart"
    allow_domains = ['topart-online.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.topart-online.com'
    ]
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS' : ['Link'] }

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/a-'), callback='parse_filter_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_filter_item(self, response):
        exists = response.xpath('.//div[@class="producteant"]').get()
        link = response.xpath('//a/@href')
        if exists:
            response.follow(url=link.get(), callback=self.parse)

        for a in link:   
            items = LinkextractorItem()
            items['Link'] = a.get()
            yield items
```

Comment: it depends that you see in logs.

Comment: @DaniilMashkin i edited my question, can you recheck it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class TopartSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'topart'
    allowed_domains = ['topart-online.com']
    start_urls = ['http://topart-online.com/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/a-'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        return {'Link': response.url}
```

Comment: why did you use ```# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-``` instead of import scrapy? and thanks, i did not thought it would be that simple/short